# accessing returned value from a second function from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller that loads a view with a tabbed panel. Depending on what item the user clicked on, data is passed as a parameter when the function `select` is invoked.

The first tab is working correctly, displaying data from the returned object.

The second tab consists of a graph. To make sure the correct data set is supplied to the graph, I need to fetch the `id` from the returned object in the first panel. In the service `loadPatentItemService` I created, when I log the returned item, it displays the correct information, though when I call this service from my controller `lineCtrl`, it logs `undefined`.

**log within factory `loadPatentItemService` service `getPatent`**

`console.log(item)`

[image]

**log returned value from calling service in `lineCtrl`**

`undefined`

Could be that when I am calling it, it is calling it for a second time and the data is reset as no argument is being passed to the function.

Basically, why can't I access the data from my controller `lineCtrl` from service `loadPatentItemService`?

```
app.factory('loadPatentItemService', function() {

    return {
        select: function(item) { 

            var patentItem = []; 
            patentItem.push(item);

            this.getPatent(patentItem);

            return patentItem;
        },
        getPatent: function(item) {
            // var hello = 'hello';
            // console.log(item);
             return item;
        }
    }

})

app.controller("lineCtrl", ['$scope', 'loadPatentItemService', function ($scope, loadPatentItemService) {

   console.log(loadPatentItemService.getPatent());

}])

app.controller('patentListCtrl', ['$scope', 'loadPatentItemService', function($scope, loadPatentItemService) {
//FUNCTION INVOKED BY USER CLICKING ON ITEM IN TABLE
    $scope.select = function(item) {
       $scope.patentItem = loadPatentItemService.select(item);
    }
}])
```

Comment: Your `getParent` function essentially does nothing. It takes one argument and returns it, that's all. Calling it without an argument returns `undefined`. You probably want to store the data as property of `this` and return _that_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `select` function, you need to store the selected item in the service so that you can send it back in the `getPatent` function.

Try changing your your `loadPatentItemService` to this

```
app.factory('loadPatentItemService', function() {
    var service = {
        selectedItem: null;
        select: function(item) { 
           service.selectedItem = item;
            return [selectedItem]; // Returning an array since your original post was returning an array
        },
        getPatent: function() {
             return service.selectedItem ;
        }
    }
    return service;
})
```

Comment: That was me being stupid. Thank you for your time and example! Do you know the issue with my question? I.e. why it got voted down?

Comment: I do not know why your question got voted down. It is a properly formatted question with sufficient information to debug.